# Android studio cannot detect google-services.json

Tags: android-studio

As the topic says, when i copy the google-services.json file to the app folder, it doesn't show up on the list to the left but when i copy it to the java or res folder it appears but obviously it wont be read because it's not meant to be there

I have triple checked the spelling and all but still nothing.

This all started when I updated to android studio 3.0 (stable) last night.

Comment: What is the error message that appears? Generally it will say something like 'looking in /path/'

Comment: sorry it was dumb, had the json file in the root folder not the app folder.